# Meaning of the phrase no doubt mindful

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the phrase **no doubt mindful** in the context of the following sentence. Does it mean **it is with no doubt mindful**

> No doubt mindful of the advice of Crown Advocate Jowitt,
> DI Pashley recorded in the investigation policy book “any audio product obtained
> within Europe will be subjected to decision on admissibility via judicial proceedings
> in any subsequent prosecution”.

[Judgment](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.jcpc.uk/decided-cases/docs/JCPC_2009_0111_Judgment.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjz1c2Vq8jtAhVhmeYKHQ5MCAwQFjAKegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw00pzkuMT1l4QZKfb5mqw2X&cshid=1607772555114)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DI Pashley was 'no doubt mindful (probably aware) of the advice...'